# ALSA can't find USB sound card

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa

I don't know what I did wrong but in Raspbian when I run

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

or

```
aplay -l
```

I can't find my USB sound card anymore whereas yesterday i hadn't this problem.

Any ideas about how to fix it please ?

Comment: Does it appear in the output of `lsusb`? Any error messages in the system log?

Comment: Yes, it does appear in the output of lsusb. And i don't have any message in the system log.

Comment: Run `rmmod snd-usb-audio` and `modprobe snd-usb-audio`. Any message then?

Comment: Any message when I run these commands...